# Google Cloud SQL App Engine API authentication

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am planning for an android application that needs database. My plan is to use Google Cloud SQL for database, and build API's using Google App Engine (GAE).
 I looked into the UserService class provided in the appengine library, developed a simple applcation to authenticate, it redirects users to the google page for login and works fine. If I use this API in an android (or any OS) application, will the user have to sign-in every time the application is launched ? I haven't tried, but I want the user to sign-in only the first time, will GAE work that way ? Just wanted to clarify.
Thanks

Comment: Try this: [Authenticating against AppEngine from an Android app](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user will only have to sign in once (that is, until he/she revokes permissions in the Google security settings).